# Bundler how to require gems separately in Gemfile just in one file?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I have a conflict between rspec and mocha (rspec is not using mocha but other minitest tests are).

If I put mocha in my gemfile (even with require: false) it gets loaded by activesupport/test_case.rb:15

```
silence_warnings { require 'mocha/setup' }
```

which then causes rspec to barf.

So, I'd like to just require it in my test_setup file from my system gems but I can't figure out how to load a gem outside of bundler.

Other ideas on how to get these gems to play nice are welcome.

Comment: Why are you mixing rspec and minitest?

Comment: Just to make my life hard.

Answer (score 1):

You can use groups in your `Gemfile`: http://bundler.io/v1.3/groups.html

> Require the gems in particular groups, noting that gems outside of a
>   named group are in the :default group
>
> ```
> Bundler.require(:default, :development)
> ```
>
> Require the default gems, plus the gems in a group
>   named the same as the current Rails environment
>
> ```
> Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)
> ```
>
> Restrict the groups of gems that
>   you want to add to the load path. Only gems in these groups will be
>   require'able
>
> ```
> require 'rubygems'
> require 'bundler'
> Bundler.setup(:default, :ci)
> require 'nokogiri'
> ```

Comment: mocha still seems to be require(able) even if I put it in a group called :foo

Answer (score 0):

Could you just install gem and require it?

```
$ gem install my_gem
```

and in testfile:

```
require 'full/path/to/my_gem.rb'
```

Comment: This didn't work because requires in mocha.rb failed.